# Where does 2.5% Zakat come from?

Tags: sharia, zakat

I was hoping that this information is in the Quran but I could not find it. Apparently the Quran only says, Pray Salat and give Zakat. Where does this value come from? Are there any variation in it among different sects?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum,

This a good question. Here are some hadith to prove the percentage.

Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Ibn Maajah.

> Ibn Abi Shaybah narrated in al-Musannad (9966) with a jayyid isnaad
>   from ‘Ali (may Allah be pleased with him) that he said: Nothing is due
>   on anything less than twenty dinars; for twenty dinars, half a dinar
>   is due; for forty dinars, one dinar is due. For anything more than
>   that, it is to be worked out. Irwa’ al-Ghaleel, 3/291

Also

Saheeh Abi Dawood.

> Ibn Maajah (1791) narrated from Ibn ‘Umar and ‘Aa’ishah (may Allah be
>   pleased with them both) that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah
>   be upon him) used to take from every twenty dinars or more, half a
>   dinar, and from forty dinars, one dinar.

From the above hadiths, the percentage is 2.5%..

For detailed answer, please consult:
http://islamqa.info/en/145600

Comment: I am sorry to say this is cut and past answer. We have been discussing these on meta. I would suggest to please add something from your own. Btw the link is useful and thanks for answering.

Comment: if the answer is based on just one hadith, then how can i ADD something else to it? as the hadith precisely answers the question?

Comment: at least you should fully credit your answer to the link you provided. In my view this is plagiarism.

Comment: @muslim1 Hadith is public domain. You could copy the whole thing without attribution and it wouldn't legally be considered plagiarism.